# Sending data from html to database

Tags: python, django, django-forms

The following partial code is a mix of HTML and python. Where a products' values (`item_name, description, item_price`) of the table `products` from my database are laid out on HTML and has a "add to cart" input button next to each item.

```
{% for product in products %}
    <li>

        <b>Name/Model:</b> {{ product['item_name'] }}<br> <b>Description:</b> {{ product['description'] }}<br> <b>Price: </b> {{ product['item_price'] }}$

        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart"/>

    </li> 
{% endfor %}
```

When add to cart is pressed, is there a way to send the information of the product next to that button to my other table called item_cart?

I'm very very new to this kind of mixed language projects, if you need extra code to help you help solve my problem ask in the comments and i will share the part of code you need.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in many ways. You can for example get the Id of each product and add it to each row you are echoing, them depending on the approach you want to take you could make the update in different ways. I can suggest maybe Ajax so you can sen the request without the necessity of reloading the page.

Comment: This looks like Django Template Language to me. I am sure there is some way to do it written in the docs.

Comment: Sorry for the bother but Eli can you be a bit more specific? I have tried searching up tutorials but because i just started doing and learning this project 3 days ago, alot of them does not make any sense. Thanks alot if you could!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you just need to create a view to do it.

Your view will have a parameter that will take `product.product_id`, like so:

```
def addToCart(request, product_id):
    p = Product.objects.filter(product_id = product_id)
    #put the product in your member's cart table,
```

Then in your template, your "add to cart" input button will call:

```
"/addToCart/{{ product.product_id }}/"
```

I hope this gives you some direction.

Comment: So is the view created in a new Python file or just added in the html file I posted? Thanks!

Comment: @pythonsohard You should have more files than just this Django Template Language (DTL) file. This file should be in a folder "templates", encompassing it is the app folder. In the app folder, there should be a `views.py` file.

Comment: When you create a new project using Django, all the files and folders are created for you. Except the template and static folder which you setup manually. The views.py file will be created in your app folder. You've to learn the basic setup of Django before moving forward, otherwise you're just shooting at the dark.